# Ubuntu/Linux tablet or laptop that can support Active Digitizer Pen Pressure Input?

Tags: tablet, graphics-tablet

I'm an illustrator and I'm in the market for a tablet or laptop with an active digitizer stylus (Wacom, N-Trig) but that can also run Ubuntu or Linux. I'd like to start to move away from iOs and Windows. What machines run Ubuntu and Linux but also have pen pressure sensitivity?

Thanks so much! Have a great day!

-Jonathan

Comment: In general, most (all?) windows 10 devices will also run Linux. But that doesn't mean that an active digitizer which works in Windows also works in Linux. For example my Wacom Intuos Pro works in Linux, but needs to be configured using command line utilities to make full use of it.